# Ruby flow control

Tags: ruby, controls, iteration

I can't find any useful resources online that breaks down Ruby's different flow-control options.

Let's assume that I'm iterating over an array within in a method:

```
def a_method
   things.each do |t|
      # control options?
   end
end
```

What are my different flow-control options here?  How do they differ?

1. retry
2. return
3. break
4. next
5. redo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`retry` can be used inside a rescue block, to jump back into the begin block after the condition that caused the exception has been remedied. Inside a block it has the effect of jumping to the beginning of the yielding method. So inside each this means that retry will jump to the beginning of the loop.

`return` will return from the method it's inside of - in this case from `a_method`.

`break` will return from the yielding method - in this case from `each` (which would be different from returning from `a_method` if something happened between the end of the each-block and the end of `a_method`).

`next` will return from the block and thus jump to the next item in `things`.

`redo` will jump to the beginning of the block and thus repeat the current iteration.